# Центрирование элементов

Tags: css, сss3

Как размещать блоки по центру, чтобы при изменении масштаба они оставались в центре? Пример - тот же самый вк

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` А если вы будете использовать `flexbox`, то вообще круто! А в целом, [WebRef](http://webref.ru) вам в помощь. :)

Comment: В центре чего? Расскажите, как в «том же самом вк», чтобы вопрос был самодостаточным)

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/189696/  https://habrahabr.ru/company/netcracker/blog/277433/ учитесь использовать гугл

Answer (score 0):

Примеров не счесть, покажу один.

```css
.centerdiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerdiv">My blok</div>
```

Данный код выровняет блок по центру страницы.